# ReactJS Performance Best Practice

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

Let's say I have a user table containing 10 rows, each row will have a modal accepting user id as its props versus only one modal and then access user id via redux for example. Which one is better for performance? By the way, I'm using chakra ui modal and I notice that the modal will get removed from the DOM when isOpen is false.

Answer (score 0):

With 10 rows you won't see a performance impact, however if I was implementing this feature I would prefer to not have it embeded within the table row.

From a code organisation POV it makes more sense that the table does its thing i.e. show data and emits events to the overarching component to handle those events. So in your case show a modal with the context passed in from
the button click on your table row.